# Disable arrow keys from scrolling only when user is interacting with <canvas>

Tags: javascript, scroll, addeventlistener, html5-canvas, event-listener

I have added an event listener in JS to listen for keyup/keydown events, I am attempting to move a sprite across the HTML canvas. I have that mostly working, but the page is being scrolled when the user presses the arrow keys.

I am returning false, and that does not seem to work. In addition, my understanding is that returning false in this manner would disable arrow button scrolling for the entire page. I would like to only disable this while the user is interacting with the canvas itself.

Here is my event listener:

```
addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    move = false;
    x = false;
    y = false;
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;
    switch(keycode){
        case 37:
            move = true;
            x = 'negative';
        break;
        case 38:
            move = true;
            y = 'negative'
        break;
        case 39:
            move = true;
            x = 'positive'
        break;
        case 40:
            move = true;
            y = 'positive'
        break;
    }
    if(move){
        animation.move(x,y);
    }
    return false;
})
```

**Edit:**

The below answer has a good idea of how to make sure that the canvas is focused, but I am still puzzled why returning false in my EventListener function which returns false is not disabling scrolling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as you are giving your canvas focus somehow (ie canvas.tabIndex = 1;) then you can just add `e.preventDefault()` right before your `return false` and it will work.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/faAkN/

Comment: Thanks.  Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and came up with a fix.

Here's what I came up with:

```
function $(){
  return document.querySelector.apply(document,arguments);
}
var canvas = $('canvas'),
    keysDown = []; // You can also define this as an object, {}
canvas.tabIndex = 0;
canvas.onclick = function(e){
  document.body.scrollTop = canvas.offsetTop; // scrolls to canvas element
  canvas.focus(); // re-focuses canvas in case the scroll unfocused it
}
canvas.onkeydown = canvas.onkeyup = function(e){
  keysDown[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
function isDown(key){
  return keysDown[key];
}
function resetMap(){
  keysDown = [];
  return false;
}
```

To check if a key is down, use `isDown(keycode)` either in an interval loop or in a keydown function.

For a regular key listener:

```
canvas.onkeydown = canvas.onkeyup = function(e){
  // [...]
  if(isDown(17) && isDown(32)){ // Ctrl + Space
    alert('Ctrl and Space were pressed');
    resetMap();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

For a rapid key listener similar to ActionScript 2.0's `Key.isDown`

```
function KeyLoop(){
  if(isDown(17) && isDown(32)){ // Ctrl + Space
    console.log('Lots of text');
    resetMap();
  }
  setTimeout(keyLoop,1000/24); // @ 24 fps
}
keyLoop();
```

I put a different action here for two reasons: 1) Mixing `alert()` with a repeating interval is never a good idea, and 2) to demonstrate the lack of delay, which is what makes this similar to the AS2 `Key.isDown()` function. To see the logged text, bring up firebug or a regular JavaScript console. In Chrome, that's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. In Firefox, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

---

This should fix your scrolling problem by focusing on the element when you click the canvas. An added benefit is that you can check for multiple keys at once since you're using `keysDown[]` as an abstraction from the original event, making an 8-directional game easy to make.

Comment: After testing it further, I realized that it wasn't scrolling to the span. It in fact scrolls to the `<input>` element, which is what I was originally using. The best thing to write for the orientation is `document.body.scrollTop=canvas.offsetTop` in the `canvas.onclick` function. While `canvas.focus()` does automatically orient to the canvas, you'll notice it leaves space at the top or bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    canvas_active = false;
</script>

<canvas onfocus="javascript: canvas_active = true;" onblur="javascript: canvas_active = false;" />
```

Then in your current method check to see if the canvas_active is true and if so, return false, else return true. This would only work if the canvas is focused the whole time they are moving it, of course.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, though I'd prefer not to do inline javascript for seperation of concerns.

Comment: An canvas element is not focusable. You could use `tabindex=0` to make it focusable.

Comment: Nice one, pimvdb. Also, Chris, you could use jQuery to bind the onfocus and onblur methods: `$('#canvas_name').focus(function() {
  canvas_active = true;
});` `$('#canvas_name').blur(function() {
  canvas_active = false;
});`